# Material iOS ErrorTextField error goes behind other views when using it inside UIStackView

Tags: ios, uistackview, cosmicmind

Material iOS ErrorTextField error goes behind other views when using it inside UIStackView.

How to solve it?

Also right to left alignment does not work.

Comment: Please share your code setup.

Comment: @CosmicMind Everything is done through stroyboard. You mean the full project?

Comment: Well I would like to replicate the issue. So the more you can provide the better, or even email support@cosmicmind.io, and then I can post a solution here. Thanks!